# How can I filter elements with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter

### Problem

I made a little script that let's checkboxes filter elements on their classnames. It kinda works, but it all crashes when I click a checkbox that's not the first or second one. I don't see why but it just does. Could someone point me in the right direction?

### Code

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dqcLjcu/3/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="filters">
    Filters:
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter" id="cat1-filter" data-filter="cat1">
    <label for="cat1-filter">category 1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="filter" id="cat2-filter" data-filter="cat2">
    <label for="cat2-filter">category 2</label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="filter" id="cat3-filter" data-filter="cat3">
    <label for="cat3-filter">category 3</label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="filter" id="cat4-filter" data-filter="cat4">
    <label for="cat4-filter">category 4</label>
</div>

<a href="#" class="item cat1">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
</a>

<a href="#" class="item cat1 cat3">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
</a>

<a href="#" class="item cat2">
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
</a>

<a href="#" class="item cat1 cat2 cat4">
    <h3>Item 4</h3>
</a>
```

The Javascript:

```
// Make filters react
var filters = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');
for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    filters[i].addEventListener('change', filter);
};

function filter () {
    // Hide all posts by default
    var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        posts[i].style.display = 'none';
    };

    // Run through all filters
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        // Check if filter is active
        if (filters[i].checked){
            // Get current filter name
            var curFilter = filters[i].getAttribute('data-filter');
            // Get all matching elements
            var visiblePosts = document.getElementsByClassName(curFilter);
            for (var i = 0; i < visiblePosts.length; i++) {
                // Show every matching element
                visiblePosts[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You're using the same variable `i` in both loops.

Comment: Thanks that must be it!

Comment: And that's why variables should be declared at the top of functions in JS. There's no local `for` loop scope.